# How can I use convertto-html to create an HTML table with dynamic columns?

Tags: powershell

How can I use convertto-html to create an HTML table with dynamic columns?

Data could be something like below (number of columns and their names will vary):

```
$ColumnHeadings = $("Col1","Col2","Col3")
$TableRows = @(("a1","b1","c1"),("a2","b2","c2"),("a3","b3","c3"),("a4","b4","c4"))
```

I have tried things like below:

```
$HTMLRows = $TableRows | convertto-html $_
$TableRows | ForEach-Object {Add-Member -InputObject $_ -Type NoteProperty -Name Value -Value $_; $_} | ConvertTo-Html -Fragment -Property Value
```

Please let me know if more info is required to give an answer.

*Edit: I found the answer myself (below), leaving the question&answer here in case I forget, or anyone else needs it.*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to put this bit of code together that solves my issue, but the columns are out of order in the html-table.. wonder why..? ***Edit:*** I found it, adjusted code below ([Ordered]).

Also, can I remove the colgroup tags?

```
$ColumnHeadings = $("Col1","Col2","Col3")
$TableRows = @(("a1","b1","c1"),("a2","b2","c2"),("a3","b3","c3"), ("a4","b4","c4"))
$columns = $ColumnHeadings.Count

$HTMLRows = $TableRows | Where-Object{$_} | ForEach-Object {
    $row = [Ordered]@{}
    For($rowIndex = 0;$rowIndex -lt $columns;$rowIndex++)
    {
        $h = $ColumnHeadings[$rowIndex]
        $row.Add($h,$_[$rowIndex])
    }
    [pscustomobject]$row
} | ConvertTo-Html -Fragment
```

Gives this neat table:

```
 <table>
 <colgroup><col/><col/><col/></colgroup>
  <tr><th>Col1</th><th>Col2</th><th>Col3</th></tr>
  <tr><td>a1</td><td>b1</td><td>c1</td></tr>
  <tr><td>a2</td><td>b2</td><td>c2</td></tr>
  <tr><td>a3</td><td>b3</td><td>c3</td></tr>
  <tr><td>a4</td><td>b4</td><td>c4</td></tr>
 </table>
```